# Piping large byte array into Process in an Android application

Tags: java, android, embedded-linux

I'm working on a project where the current structure makes the most
sense to send a 1.2MB file to stdin of a managed ARM process.
In Java, this process is created with `ProcessBuilder`,
and trying to write to the process's output stream with
`os.write(buf)` results in
the following stack trace, indicating that the write
caused the process/pipe to terminate.
This write has been working for smaller buffers
of 100's of bytes.

[image]

I've tried using Apache's IOUtils, BufferedOutputStream,
and OutputStreamWriter, but they all cause the process to terminate.

I've tried chunking the writes to sending 1k bytes at a
time as in the following snippet.

```
int chunkSize = 1000, sentBytes = 0, i = 0;
while (sentBytes < b.length) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Writing chunk " + i);
    int sz = sentBytes+chunkSize > b.length ? b.length % chunkSize : chunkSize;
    os.write(b, i*chunkSize, sz);
    os.flush();
    sentBytes += chunkSize; i++;
}
```

However, this is only able to send 68k bytes before crashing.
I've run this multiple times and the code consistently crashes
while writing chunk 68.

[image]

I tried making a minimal working example [here](https://gist.github.com/bamos/fa4c8885d3d9bf525ad0) to try
to isolate this problem. However, this code completely
hangs when trying to write 1MB of data.
This code acts correctly when writing 100 bytes.

I'm not sure if I'm searching for the right terms, but the
following are some related posts I found, none addressing
this problem.

- [Sending Large files as stream to process.getOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171213/sending-large-files-as-stream-to-process-getoutputstream)
- [write (byte[] b) optim usage for large byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483050/write-byte-b-optim-usage-for-large-byte-array)

So, how can I correctly write a large (1.2MB) file to an `OutputStream`
of a `Process` managed in Android Java?
What are some other approaches I can try?

My backup plan is to modify the subprocess to not read this much data
from `stdin`, but this modification is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second problem first.  `ProcessBuilder`, by default, will arrange for your child process' `stdin` and `stdout` to be connected to your program.  Your test program spawns `cat` and writes 1 MB of data to its `stdin`.  But `cat`'s job is to copy its `stdin` to its `stdout`, and you never read from its `stdout`!  Once the kernel's pipe buffer fills up, `cat` will therefore block when trying to write.  Since it is blocked, it is no longer reading data from its `stdin`, so your program blocks in turn.

Your original program has a different problem: the write is failing on `EPIPE`, not hanging.  As you point out, this means that your child process has terminated (or at least has closed its `stdin`).  Your helper process doesn't know or care which Java API you're using: it's just reading from a pipe, and there's nothing in the POSIX pipe mechanism that can cause a pipe *reader* to exit.  (Writers, on the other hand, can be killed with `SIGPIPE` if the last reader disappears.)  Have you ruled out the possibility that something in the **content** of the data you're sending is causing your helper process to exit?

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't sending the correct data to the input stream of my program. Thanks!